# How to close a WPF child window using MVVM without any MVVM frameworks?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am very new to MVVM and WPF.

The application I have created has two buttons, openWindow and closeWindow.
I managed to hook up the openWindow using the ICommand and go it to open a new window :)
My question is how when I press that closeWindow, do I close that opened window?

I am not using any MVVM frameworks like MVVM Light etc.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Use codebehind.  UI work is done by the UI layer, not the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

why you wanna close a window from another window? makes no sense to me and its not that userfriendly. nevertheless you can always expose an event in your viewmodel which the view can subscribe and react to. you do not break the mvvm pattern with such events.

Comment: Hey Blindmeis. See I am trying to wrap my head around how to MVVM works --> Coming from a windows forms background, normally, I'd pass an instance of that child window then I can close it easily by referencing that instance. Here with mvvm, I dont even know if its possible to pass an instance of the window around.

Comment: You just need to reverse the thinking slightly - instead of the parent holding a reference to the child, the child should be aware of the parent and respond to it's events. Pass your main window VM object to the child window as a parameter, then the child can subscribe to any events (including a close event) from the parent that it needs to.

Comment: if you wanna do mvvm you should forget the views/windows at all ;) think in viewmodels and how they are related. the view and usercontrol are just the visual reprensentation. just edit your question i write what you wanna achieve. e.g i want that my mainview can open a dialog where he user can edit data and then with ok/cancel these data are back in the mainview. this is easy to achieve with mvvm.